# MYSQL select query for a report

Tags: mysql

I got stuck in a problem where I need to select the desired output for a table

```
id |    phone   | ---- | is_lead_closed |     closed_date
-- | -----------| ---- | ---------------| -------------------
1  | 9999999999 | ---- |      null      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
2  | 9999999999 | ---- |       1        | 2017-02-01 10:00:00
3  | 9999999999 | ---- |      null      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  
4  | 9999999999 | ---- |      null      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
5  | 9999999999 | ---- |      null      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
6  | 9999999999 | ---- |      null      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
7  | 9999999999 | ---- |       1        | 2017-02-10 10:00:00
```

Here I need in output last counts of lead after the closer of previous lead
i.e., 5 which is the count after last close.

ok i got upto this point 
This is my data table

```
id | lms_lead_id | ameyo_lead_id | call_time | is_lead_closed | lead_close_date
177452 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-06 10:07:31" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
182023 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-06 15:09:00" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
182197 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-06 15:20:12" | 1 | "2017-02-06 19:30:47"
182283 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-06 15:29:21" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
183857 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-06 17:30:20" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
187708 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-07 12:38:38" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
188767 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-07 13:31:50" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
191257 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-07 15:36:42" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
192978 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-07 16:44:33" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
195362 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-07 17:47:02" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
196710 | 1387790 | 682 | "2017-02-07 18:33:23" | 1 | "2017-02-07 20:00:33"
209832 | 1387790 | 396 | "2017-02-09 15:33:49" | NULL | "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```

I have created query so far is

```
select
a.lms_lead_id,
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(close_status
SEPARATOR ''),
'1',
- 2)) as attempts,
DATEDIFF(max(call_time), min(call_time)) AS days
from
(select
llct.lms_lead_id,
if(llct.is_lead_closed = 1, 1, 0) as close_status,
llct.call_time
from
lms_ameyo_call_tracker llct
inner join lms_ameyo_call_tracker llct_1 ON llct.lms_lead_id = llct_1.lms_lead_id
and llct_1.is_lead_closed = 1
and date(llct_1.lead_close_date) between '2017-02-07' and '2017-02-07'
and llct.ameyo_lead_id = llct_1.ameyo_lead_id
where
llct.ameyo_lead_id = 682) as a
group by a.lms_lead_id;
```

where lms_ameyo_call_tracker is the table name now i stuck with fetching call_time

Comment: I don't get your requirement. Could you be specific

Comment: My requirement is to fetch the counts from the table before previous closed i.e, the data with id 3 till 7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight i have added my working code. what i need is to understand the logic to implement

Comment: No pictures, thanks.

Comment: sorry i am newbee in asking question thanks @Strawberry for making me correct

Answer (score 0):

I assume if the value of is_lead_closed  column is 1, then it's the closure of the corresponding lead. **In such case you have to get the second most max ID with is_lead_closed = 1 and the highest ID with is_lead_closed  = 1. And then count number of rows in between these two IDs**.

Following query should do the job, but can be optimized.

select count(*) from table where id >  (select max(id) from table where id not in (select max(id) from table where is_lead_closed = 1) and is_lead_closed = 1) and id <= (select max(id) from table where is_lead_closed = 1)

Comment: Thanks @Sisir i have checked the query but get stuck in between execution as the table contains millions of records in it.

Comment: Yes, this is a developer kind of query, I am not a DBA. To fasten up the execution, please create an index on **is_lead_closed**